# Is there any way to enable the PIP programatically

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

Am developing an app using PIP when the user turned off PIP in settings. I can check only the PIP is enable or not is there any way to enable pip Programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't as Android OS needs consent of user to enable PIP (Picture-in-Picture) . However you can show user a dialog box regarding activation of PIP and on action button open app's setting page from where he can manually enable PIP.

Code to Open Setting Page :

```
val intent = Intent(
Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent("android.settings.PICTURE_IN_PICTURE_SETTINGS", Uri.parse("package:$packageName")), 0)
```

It will also scroll to and highlight your application